# ¿Cómo recorrer un arreglo de objetos en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Quiero recorrer un arreglo de objetos mediante una iteracion para obtener un atributo en particular de cada objeto pero no sé como hacerlo, he probado  generando un `getCanción()` que reciba como argumento el indice del arreglo, haciéndolo directamente de la forma `cancion[i]`(como se muestra en el código), pasándolo a otro arreglo tipo int para luego ocupar ese y todas las formas me provocan un segmentation fault. Les dejo el método de la clase que me provoca dicho error. De ante mano muchas gracias. Edit: Agregue las clases y el main para clarificar más el problema. P.d: El problema es en la clase Álbum, específicamente en el método duracionTotal y Imprimir_Canciones. Al compilar y ocuparlos en el main el programa se cierra con un segmentation fault.

```
class Canciones{
private:
    string letra;
    int duracion;
public:
Canciones (string _letra, int dur){
    letra = _letra;
    duracion = dur;
}
void setletra(string letra){
    this->letra = letra;
}
void setduracion(int duracion){
    this->duracion = duracion;
}
int getDuracion(){
return this->duracion;
}
string getLetra(){
    return this->letra;
}

};
class Grupo{
protected:
    string nombre_g;
    int fecha;
public:
Grupo (string nombre_g, int fecha){
    this->nombre_g = nombre_g;
    this->fecha = fecha;
}
};

class Album: public Grupo{
public:
    string nombre_a;
    int ano;
    Canciones *cancion[11];

Album(string nombre_g,int fecha,string nombre_a,int ano):Grupo(nombre_g, 
fecha){
    this->nombre_a = nombre_a;
    this->ano = ano;
    for (int i=0; i<11; i++){
        cancion [i] = new Canciones ("letra",3);
    }       
}
Canciones *getCancion(int a){
    return this->cancion[a];
}

void duracionTotal(){
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<11;i++){
        suma += cancion[i]->getDuracion();
        }
        cout<<suma; 

}
void Imprime_Canciones(){
    for (int i=0;i<11;i++){
        cout<<getCancion(i)->getLetra()<<endl;
    }
}
};

int main(){
Album *nuevo;
nuevo->duracionTotal();
return 0;}
```

Comment: Podrias poner los atributos de estos objetos?

Comment: @ChechoParrado Listo, editado. Gracias desde ya.

Comment: He publicado un respuesta, pero me veo en la obligación de votar para cerrar como `error tipográfico`.

Comment: @Trauma Si, sobre eso. Manipulando el código cometí ese error de tipeo (corregido), mas, no soluciona el problema ya que este se provoca en el método de la otra clase.

Answer (score 1):

Lo de usar el mismo nombre para los argumentos de las funciones-miembro y para las variables-miembro te va a dar mas de un problema en el futuro, aparte de que tener que poner `this->XXX` es mas largo. Sobre gustos ...

```
Canciones( string _letra, int dur ) {
  letra = letra;
  duracion = duracion;
}

Grupo( string nombre_g, int fecha ) {
  nombre_g = nombre_g;
  fecha = fecha;
}
```

Te has equivocado al poner los nombres. Cámbialo por

```
Canciones( string _letra, int dur ) {
  letra = _letra;
  duracion = dur;
}

Grupo( string nombre_g, int fecha ) {
  this->nombre_g = nombre_g;
  this->fecha = fecha;
}
```

Y asunto resuelto :-)

Answer (score 1):

Otra posibilidad (que además te permite detectar el error comentado por @Trauma en tiempo de compilación es inicializar las variables miembro llamando a su constructor correspondiente:

```
Canciones( string _letra, int dur )
  : letra(_letra), duracion(_duracion)
{ }

Grupo( string nombre_g, int fecha )
  : nombre_g(nombre_g), fecha(fecha)
{ }
```

Fíjate como en el caso de `Grupo` el programa compila perfectamente. El motivo es que después de los dos puntos el compilador solo te va a dejar inicializar las variables miembro... luego en caso de colisión de nombres la ambigüedad se resuelve sola (no puedes inicializar una variable no miembro y no puedes inicializar una variable consigo misma)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, el error era más simple. En el main estaba creando un objeto pero sin inicializarlo, eso me provocaba el error. Dejo la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien.